# img = Image.open(fp) AttributeError: class Image has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, image, pdf, python-imaging-library

I want to put the pictures into a PDF file.  My code follows...

```
import sys
import xlrd
from PIL import Image
import ImageEnhance
from reportlab.platypus import *
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize
PAGE_HEIGHT=defaultPageSize[1]

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

Title = "Integrating Diverse Data Sources with Gadfly 2"

Author = "Aaron Watters"

URL = "http://www.chordate.com/"

email = "arw@ifu.net"

from reportlab.lib.units import inch

pageinfo = "%s / %s / %s" % (Author, email, Title)

def myFirstPage(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    #canvas.setStrokeColorRGB(1,0,0)
    #canvas.setLineWidth(5)
    #canvas.line(66,72,66,PAGE_HEIGHT-72)
    canvas.setFont('Times-Bold',16)
    canvas.drawString(108, PAGE_HEIGHT-108, Title)
    canvas.setFont('Times-Roman',9)
    canvas.drawString(inch, 0.75 * inch, "First Page / %s" % pageinfo)
    canvas.restoreState()

def myLaterPages(canvas, doc):
    #canvas.drawImage("snkanim.gif", 36, 36)
    canvas.saveState()
    #canvas.setStrokeColorRGB(1,0,0)
    #canvas.setLineWidth(5)
    #canvas.line(66,72,66,PAGE_HEIGHT-72)
    canvas.setFont('Times-Roman',9)
    canvas.drawString(inch, 0.75 * inch, "Page %d %s" % (doc.page, pageinfo))
    canvas.restoreState()

def go():
    Elements.insert(0,Spacer(0,inch))
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate('ss.pdf')
    doc.build(Elements,onFirstPage=myFirstPage, onLaterPages=myLaterPages)

Elements = []

HeaderStyle = styles["Heading1"] # XXXX

def header(txt, style=HeaderStyle, klass=Paragraph, sep=0.3):
    s = Spacer(0.2*inch, sep*inch)
    Elements.append(s)
    para = klass(txt, style)
    Elements.append(para)

ParaStyle = styles["Normal"]

def p(txt):
    return header(txt, style=ParaStyle, sep=0.1)

def open_excel(file= 'exc.xls'):
    try:
        data = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
        return data
    except Exception,e:
        print str(e)

#pre = p # XXX

PreStyle = styles["Code"]

def pre(txt):
    s = Spacer(0.1*inch, 0.1*inch)
    Elements.append(s)
    p = Preformatted(txt, PreStyle)
    Elements.append(p)
p("""\
Relational databases manipulate and store persistent
table structures called relations, such as the following
three tables""")

fp = open("/pdf-ex/downloadwin7.png","rb")
img = Image.open(fp)
img.show()
# HACK
Elements.append(PageBreak())


go()
```

Comment: Tell us here you're stuck and give us the smallest amount of code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You can't ask for help by giving all that stuff, esp. all these uncommon modules! I have jept only PIL Image and the 2 statements  of opening and showing an image and there's no problem. From my experience the error _"class Image has no attribute 'open'"_ occurs when PIL Image is imported before other modules, e.g. Tkinter (there might be some conflicts). Try importing it at the end.

Answer (score 75):

You have a namespace conflict.  One of your import statements is masking `PIL.Image` (which is a module, not a class) with some class named `Image`.

Instead of ...

```
from PIL import Image
```

try ...

```
import PIL.Image
```

then later in your code...

```
fp = open("/pdf-ex/downloadwin7.png","rb")
img = PIL.Image.open(fp)
img.show()
```

When working with a LOT of imports, beware of namespace conflicts.  I'm generally very wary of `from some_module import *` statements.

Good luck with your project and happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There is no wrong to run the program.But the picture couldn't be opened.

Comment: @wangling the solution I gave solves the problem that is described by your post's title.  As to the overall problem of adding images to the .pdf file, I can't answer as the information needed to answer that is FAR beyond what is presented in the post.  However, from my cursory knowledge of reportlab, I think you're on the right track.  Keep working at it and you'll have it solved, soon.

Comment: I had this issue when importing `from PIL import Image, ImageTk` in a main file, and `from PIL import Image` in a secondary file that was being imported to the main file. Specifying the import as `import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk` and `import PIL.Image` in the respective files solved the issue described in this answer. Commenting as I wasn't aware the namespace conflict could stem from importing the same Class/Module in two files, where one imports the other.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem with TKInter in a single file:

I changed:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import *
```

to:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
```

and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution I could find.

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
```