# class Image has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [img = Image.open(fp) AttributeError: class Image has no attribute ‘open’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748822/img-image-openfp-attributeerror-class-image-has-no-attribute-open)

So I am trying to view pictures in python with tkinter. I installed PIL and I am trying to open a picture but I keep getting an attribute error saying "class Image has no attribute 'open'

```
from __future__ import division
from PIL import Image
from Tkinter import *
import random

img = Image.open("majestic creature.jpeg").convert("RGB")
```

This isn't all the code I have but this is the part that the program seems to have trouble with.

Comment: I've already seen that post. I tried the solution and it gave me another error:
    IOError: cannot identify image file

Comment: edited the comment to include the error. Prematurely pressed enter.

Comment: are you sure that it is not "`majestic creature.jpg`" (not jpeg) or a typo in the file name?

Comment: nope, I just checked, it is jpg. I tried changing it to jpeg and it gave me a different error saying: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'majestic creature.jpeg'

Comment: wait, in your code it is `jpeg`. You said in the comment that the file name ends in `jpg`. Is that the problem? Also, it's spelled "majestic." Is that a typo or is the file named that?

Comment: So there was some confusion in the file type, but I changed it to make sure they are consistent and it is still giving me the error: IOError: cannot identify image file

Comment: um... sorry, I have no clue about this now

Comment: Do you know if theres any resources you can offer to help me out? Its for an assignment and I've been trying to figure this error out for hours with no progress.

Comment: This may help a little. If you split the statement into two lines (the first opening the image, the second converting to rgb) it may be easier to find your problem. Also a minor gripe but you might want to avoid using filenames with spaces in them

Comment: If you knew about the linked question, which exactly covers the problem you asked in the question, then why did you ask another question on the same topic although you have a completely different error?

Comment: Please _paste your traceback_, don't transcribe it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the looks of what you have said, namely `This is not all of the code`.
You or some other import has declared some variable / class called `Image` and this has overwritten the `Image` class that was imported by `PIL`.

To specifically use the `PIL` `Image` class use:

```
img = PIL.Image.open("majestic creature.jpeg").convert("RGB")
```

Comment: I don't know why but if I import `from Tkinter import*` first and before of `from PIL import Image` it works

Comment: Probably because TKinter has an image class which the PIL import is overriding when it's after the `from Tkinter import *`. Incidentally I always encourage explicit exports for this reason. http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter-module.html