# Module 'image' has no attribute 'Image'

Tags: python-3.x

While working in python 3.8 doing Image processing.

I am getting `AttributeError: module 'image' has no attribute 'Image'`

I have installed the package image and package cImage both. Help me out

Comment: Is this help to your solution: [enter link description here][here] [here]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748822/img-image-openfp-attributeerror-class-image-has-no-attribute-open

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you take the [tour] and read [ask] - your question really needs both an [mre] of the code that is causing the problem, and the complete TraceBack of the error.