# Tkinter Background Image not showing up

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, background-image, photoimage

I am trying to create a weather App in Tkinter GUI. It is working fine. I want to add a background image to it but it wont show up. initially i did it without the reference line but it didnt work. On some website they said to keep reference of the image but that too didnt work.
Also my Tkinter window size is 1920x1080 and the image was of same dimension but it still doesnt show up. I tried to reduce image size than window but still not working. Any suggestions accepted. Also there is no error.

```
bg = PhotoImage('clearsky2.jpg')
bgl = Label(gui,image=bg)
bgl.image = bg #given a reference
bgl.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1,relheight=1)
bgl.pack()
```

Comment: Although you create a reference, you pass the `bg` instead of it as the Label's image argument, and, consequently, it has no effect. You need to give the reference before you assign an image to the `bgl` label, and **pass this reference, not the bg** to the `bgl` Label.

Comment: Also, AFAIK `tkinter.PhotoImage` doesn't support JPEG images, although `PIL.ImageTk` does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its sad that `tkinter.PhotoImage` does not support `JPEG` files, but it does support `PNG` in the newer version and has proper support for `GIF` too. To use `JPEG` you need `PIL` installed.
In the terminal say:

```
pip install Pillow
```

After that import it like:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
```

Then now, to open the image with PIL, say:

```
img_file = Image.open('clearsky2.jpg')
bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_file)
bgl = Label(gui,image=bg)
bgl.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1,relheight=1)
```

This will work with `JPEG` and `PNG` files as well and, keep in mind you dont need to keep a reference unless your looping over images or creating image inside of a function.

Hope it cleared your problem, do let me know if any more errors

Cheers

Comment: Hey I am having errors. I tried installing PIL in anaconda prompt but it said "cant find a version that satisfies requirement PIL". And there is already installed PIL in anaconda. I tried your code for using it but it has another error "module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'Open' " What must I do? Also I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748822/img-image-openfp-attributeerror-class-image-has-no-attribute-open

Comment: @Coder123 `PIL.Image`? try from `PIL import Image`

Comment: Yes I did from PIL import Image, ImageTk

Comment: which version of python are you using, and what is the error

Comment: I am using python 3.7 and it gives error " PIL.Image' has no attribute 'Open' " though I did PIL import Image, ImageTk

Comment: @Coder123 try `import PIL` and say `PIL.Image.Open(...)`

Comment: Hey Thanks it worked! But it is not showing on entire window this is the output https://drive.google.com/file/d/13SZQK9i1uXd7Qq4p-3KMTMZnhSFJJtXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes whole window. But I want it above labels. I mean i want only text and those entry panes and button above image. Rest must be image and not the grey window

Comment: Actually that depends on the labels background and so on. You might need to ask a new Q for that

Comment: Yes I just now tried changing width and background showed up on more area. I will ask new question. Thank you for your help! It worked!

Comment: @Coder123 hi, did `PIL.Image.Open(...)` work? actually i think it was `from PIL import Image` and then `Image.open(...)`  with small 'o'.

Comment: Yes it worked ...I know that o in open is small I tried to edit your answer but they said minimum 6 characters edit needed..so I ignored it and I did from PIL import Image, ImageTk